# How to use apply in given function

Tags: r, function, matrix, apply, determinants

I have the following code:

```
f=function(a,b) det((rbind(cbind(a,b),c(b,2))))

K=matrix(0,nrow(x),1)
G=matrix(0,length(X),1)
for( i in 1:length(X) )
{
for( j in 1:nrow(x) )
{
K[j,]=f(X[[i]],x[j,])
}
G[i,]=max(K)
}
```

where `X` is a list of matrices and `x` is a matrix.

How I can use an `apply()` function to have faster results?

**EDIT**

Let a matrix of list `X` be the following:

```
3 0 0 
0 3 0 
0 0 3
```

and the matrix `x` has the folowing rows:

```
0 0 0
1 1 1
```

Then, we create the following matrices:

```
3 0 0 0
0 3 0 0
0 0 3 0
0 0 0 2

3 0 0 1
0 3 0 1
0 0 3 1
1 1 1 2
```

Then we find the determinants for both of them, that is `54` and `27`, respectively.

So, I choose `54`, since `54>27`.

Hence, a preferable output would be a `q` such that `q=54`.

But I have lots of matrices in list `X` and lots of rows in matrix `x`.

Comment: If you've prespecified the result variables, it might not be faster to use apply.

Comment: @RussHyde what do you mean by prespecified the result variables?

Comment: Please describe what you want the function to do. Also please give a reproducible example, along with expected outcome

Comment: @Sotos I use `R` language. Also, I want the function to find the maximum determinant for each matrix of list `X` when I augment this matrix by row and by column with each row of matrix `x`. The last diagonal element is 2.

Comment: Yes, I know. You tagged it.

Comment: Sorry. Updates to your K and G variables won't be particularly slow, since you've already told R the size and datatype that is going to be stored within those variables. The main hit on for loops is when people use the rolling-combine  `x <- c(); for(i in my_range){x <- c(x, i)}`. Calculating your determinants will take considerably longer than updating  the values in K and G

Comment: @RussHyde I have to calculate the determinants. So, you suggest to not store the determinants for each row of matrix `x`? Sorry, but I do not understand your suggestion.

Comment: All I'm saying is that calculating the determinants will take much more time than storing the resulting values in K or G; and so you won't gain from rewriting this using `apply` instead of `for`